# Add transparency to wordpress color picker?

Tags: themes, options, color-picker

Question: How could you add a few transparency options (none, semi-transparent and solid) to the chosen color in the wp color picker?

I'm working on a set of theme options. I am using the wp color picker wheel to select a color for the post backgrounds. A transparency option would fantastic if that is possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use the built-in color picker. It is [hard to use](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2012/06/26/round-3-of-this-discovery-cycle-is/) already and it will be [replaced in 3.5 anyway](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21206). You will need a custom one to get transparency.

Comment: OMG - I was so happy I got the color picker to work, and now it's history?!! Why can't things just stand still (for a while anyway). Thanks for the advice ;-)

Comment: Watch the video. You **will** understand why. :D

Comment: LOL :-)  That is exactly what I'm battling against. Trying to create an attractive & intuitive (EASY) UI for wp themes.

Maybe there's an ongoing project or something I should know about??

Comment: 0 search results for posts containing mini-colors :O

Comment: "Maybe there's an ongoing project or something I should know about??" Well there is; it's called WordPress ;-)

Comment: Yeah - just figured that :) They've got to do something about the backend. I can create nice looking themes, but going into the dashboard's like going back in time to the 80's. I see there's a patch to convert the color picker to minicolors, but no idea how to use it, yet...

Comment: But the new color picker from wordpress is in the current 3.5 beta and you can use it.